# Installing PulP with Command Prompt

Tags: python, pip

I am very new to Python and just wanted to install Pulp over Command Prompt. When done so, this came up:

```
C:\Users\DEANMAU>python -m pip install -U pulp==2.1
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pulp==2.1 in c:\users\...
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.1 in c:\users\...
```

Can anyone give me a hint on how to proceed here?

Comment: Are you sure the Python versions are the same? The one from your command prompt is probably not the right one. Have a look in PyCharm and see which Python Executable is selected. Make sure to install PuLP using *that* executable, not the default one

Comment: I'm using Python 3.9 in PyCharm. So how do I install PulP with this executable? with: python 3.9 -m pip install -U pulp==2.1 ...it doesn't work - sorry, I'm really new to all of this.

Comment: Open a terminal within PyCharm and run `python --version` If it returns 3.9, you can just do the original command

Comment: It returned 3.9.5. I did the original command (and also tried with 3.9.5) but get back the traceback as before. Might talk to a colleague about this with whom I can share my screen. Thank you very much for your help!